# Can't get result from two UITextField on swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

```
var widthValue : Int = 0
var heightValue : Int = 0
var result : Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var widthText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var heightText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var resultText: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    widthText.text = "\(widthValue)"
    heightText.text = "\(heightValue)"
    resultText.text  = "\(widthValue + heightValue)"
}
```

Two UITextFields to hold an `Int` then `resultText` displays in a `UILabel` named `resultText`.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is a useless problem description. If it does not compile What are the exact error messages? If it runs: What is the actual and the expected result?

Comment: And the answer to *"is it me"* is of course "yes"!

Answer (score 1):

I figure you're trying to add numbers from two text fields.
For that,
Change following

```
resultText.text  = "\(widthValue + heightValue)"
```

To

```
let additionResult = widthText.text + heightText.text
resultText.text = additionResult
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the values of widthText and heightText. Something like this would work

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: UIView) {
  resultText.text  = String(Int(heightText.text!)! + Int(widthText.text!)!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that I have experienced so many problems with Xcode crashing and giving me weird errors that I got totally confused - I am from the early days of Xcode and C that I am having to start all over - your above code works but only for whole numbers and crashes on say 12.4 don't supposed you have time for a fix but if so I would appreciate it

Comment: Its ok fixed with a Double

Comment: @JerGriffin glad it worked. Mark it as the accepted answer if it's working